# AWS API Gateway mTLS - Access denied. Reason: self signed certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, mtls

I've been following this guide by AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-mutual-tls-authentication-for-amazon-api-gateway/ pretty much to the letter.

This is how I generate the certs:

```
openssl genrsa -out RootCA.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key RootCA.key -out RootCA.pem

openssl genrsa -out my_client.key 2048
openssl req -new -key my_client.key -out my_client.csr

openssl x509 -req -in my_client.csr -CA RootCA.pem -CAkey RootCA.key -set_serial 01 -out my_client.pem -days 3650 -sha256
```

So now I have exactly 5 files:

```
RootCA.key
RootCA.pem
my_client.csr
my_client.key
my_client.pem
```

I then upload the `RootCA.pem` as `truststore.pem` to S3, and copied the URI into API Gateway.

Then, I make the request: `curl --key ./my_client.key --cert ./my_client.pem https://my-endpoint`

API Gateway simply returns `{"message":"Forbidden"}` with HTTP 403. In Cloudwatch log, this is what I get: `Access denied. Reason: self signed certificate`.

The endpoint works perfectly fine if I disable mTLS, so it's not an issue with the endpoint or route itself.

I've looked at this page: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-mutual-tls-403-errors/ , there's a possibility that the generated cert is invalid? But I'm not sure how to generate the correct one, as all the other guides pretty much generates the cert the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually resolved this a while ago after talking with AWS Support.

The reason for the error was the **Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name)**(when generating the keys) cannot be the same. I mistakenly used the same name because I assumed they needed to match.

For example, when generating your Root CA, if you've entered MyRootCA when prompted for **Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name)**, then when generating your client certificate, the Common Name **must not** be MyRootCA

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and followed all the steps mentioned in AWS mTls troubleshoot page https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-mutual-tls-403-errors/ but couldn't found the exact root cause. Finally I disabled the mTLS in API Gateway custom domain. Regenerated the client certificate using open ssl and uploaded it in S3 Truststore. Finally, enabled the mTLS in API gateway custom domain(It take few minutes before it can reflect the mTLS changes). This fixed my issue of forbidden message from API gateway with mTLS.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue after following the guide on https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/compute/introducing-mutual-tls-authentication-for-amazon-api-gateway/ and what fixed it for me was exporting my certificate and adding it to the truststore aswell.

I exported my certificate direcly from my browser but you can also use openssl:
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect [www.example.com:443](http://www.example.com:443) </dev/null

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).